# How do I display a Django form correctly using ListView

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am writing a simple app to track sales leads based on the Django tutorial "Writing your first Django app" (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/). Everything works well except for displaying a ListView of the existing leads.

Here are the relevant python snippets:

Leads/models.py

```
class Leads(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    last = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    first = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

config/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    # Django admin
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    # User management
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),

    # Local apps
    path('leads/', include('leads.urls'))
```

leads/urls.py

```
app_name = 'leads'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', LeadsListView.as_view(), name='list'),
    path('<int:pk>/', LeadsDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
]
```

leads/views.py

```
class LeadsListView(ListView):
    model = Leads
    template_name = 'leads/list.html'
    context_object_name = 'leads_list'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Leads.objects.order_by('id')

class LeadsDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Leads
    template_name = 'leads/detail.html'
```

The link in the 'home.html' template, which displays a menu option correctly:

```
<a href="{% url 'leads:list' %}">Leads</a>
```

And finally, the 'list.html' template that does not display at all. Instead of showing the list of leads, it remains on the home page.

```
{% block content %}
{% for lead in lead_list %}
<div class="lead-entry">
    <h2><a href="{% url 'leads:detail' lead.pk %}">{{ lead.fname }} {{ lead.lname }}</a></h2>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

I'm missing something fundamental here....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some minor mistakes such as:

#### Issue

1. The `context_object_name='leads_list`, and you have defined in your template file as `lead_list`, missed the `s`.
2. Your Model field's name is `first` and `last`, not `fname` and `lname`.

##### Solution:

Try this out in your template:

```
{% block content %}
{% for lead in leads_list %}
<div class="lead-entry">
    <h2><a href="{% url 'leads:detail' lead.pk %}">{{ lead.first }} {{ lead.last }}</a></h2>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

I have changed `lead.fname` to `lead.first` and `lead.lname` to `lead.last` and also add `s` to `lead_list`, it is now `leads_list`.

> `Note:` Models in django doesn't require its name in plural form, it would be better if you only give name model name `Lead` rather than `Leads`, as django itself adds `s` as the suffix.

> `Note:` If you are overriding the default `AutoField` generated by django which is `id`, so you must override it with [`AutoField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#autofield)<sup>[django-doc]</sup>  rather than making `IntegerField` primary key.